# How to unhide the excel rows, without expanding grouped rows in excel?

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins, add-in, excel-addins

I'm working on react excel add-in and have a requirement to unhide the hidden rows. this is working fine with `range.rowHidden=false`.

but the problem here is that grouped rows also expand.

[image: group]

How to fix this issue?

Any kind of help much be is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rajath, the Outlining feature in Excel is using the Hide/Unhide feature to hide and show rows and columns within a group. If you choose to unhide rows/columns in a collapsed group, then those rows/columns will become visible regardless of the expanded/collapsed state of the group. I don't think there is a way to work around this behavior.

Comment: Yes Jakob, you're right even though I have done enough research on that but couldn't find the solution. This is the user-requested feature that I'm currently working on. Anyhow thanks for your response.